# Small question about the output form of the derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I have an expression:

```
D[D[Subscript[T, 1][x[t], y[t], x'[t]] + Subscript[T, 2][x[t], y[t], y'[t]], x'[t]], t]
```

The result is:

$y'(t) T_1{}^{(0,1,1)}\left(x(t),y(t),x'(t)\right)+x'(t)
   T_1{}^{(1,0,1)}\left(x(t),y(t),x'(t)\right)+x''(t)
   T_1{}^{(0,0,2)}\left(x(t),y(t),x'(t)\right)$

I need to make it so that when differentiating with respect to time, variables $x'(t)$ and $y'(t)$ are not taken out of brackets.

Comment: What do you mean by "not be taken out of brackets"? Can you give a simpler example reproducing your problem, and include your desired output?

Comment: @MarcoB see my edit

Comment: You changed the questions completely so now the answers no longer match your question. That's not cool. I've reverted your edits so the question and answer match. Please ask a new different question on the new topic of sorting the order of the derivatives.

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use [`HoldForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html)

```
(expr = HoldForm[
   D[D[Subscript[T, 1][x[t], y[t], x'[t]] + 
      Subscript[T, 2][x[t], y[t], y'[t]], x'[t]], t]])
```

[image]

```
expr // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
expr // ReleaseHold
```

[image]

**EDIT:** To reverse the order of the products

```
expr2 = HoldForm[D[D[f[x[t], y''[t], z''[t], x'[t]], x'[t]], t]]
```

[image]

```
expr2 // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
expr2r = (expr2 // ReleaseHold) /. Times[a_, b_] :> HoldForm[Times[b, a]]
```

[image]

```
expr2r // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:** For the revised question

```
expr3 = Derivative[2][x][t]*
    Derivative[0, 0, 2, 0, 0][f][x[t], y[t], Derivative[1][x][t], 
     Derivative[2][y][t], Derivative[3][z][t]] + 
   Derivative[3][y][t]*
    Derivative[0, 0, 1, 1, 0][f][x[t], y[t], Derivative[1][x][t], 
     Derivative[2][y][t], Derivative[3][z][t]] + 
   Derivative[1][y][t]*
    Derivative[0, 1, 1, 0, 0][f][x[t], y[t], Derivative[1][x][t], 
     Derivative[2][y][t], Derivative[3][z][t]] + 
   Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0, 0][f][x[t], y[t], Derivative[1][x][t], 
    Derivative[2][y][t], Derivative[3][z][t]] + 
   Derivative[4][z][t]*
    Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0, 1][f][x[t], y[t], Derivative[1][x][t], 
     Derivative[2][y][t], Derivative[3][z][t]] + 
   Derivative[1][x][t]*
    Derivative[1, 0, 1, 0, 0][f][x[t], y[t], Derivative[1][x][t], 
     Derivative[2][y][t], Derivative[3][z][t]];

(expr3r = expr3 /. Plus :> Inactive[Plus] /.
    Inactive[Plus][a__, b_, c_] :> Inactive[Plus][a, c, b]) // 
      TraditionalForm
```

[image]

For subsequent operations [`Activate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html) `expr3r`

Comment: show more, please, how to sort the terms by the order of the derivative in the final expression

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Edit your question to show the output that you expect.

Comment: Are there any alternatives using the `Sort` or `SortBy` commands?

Comment: Look at my code please. Did I choose the right path? For example, I use: 

`eqn = y[t] + f[z[t], y[t]] y''[t] + b[y[t]] y'''[t] + y'[t] == 0`
`format = Inactive[Plus] @@ Reverse[List @@ (Collect[#, {x_[t], Derivative[_][x_][t]}])] &`
`format@eqn[[1]] == 0`

I get this from here; https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265681/re-sorting-higher-order-ordinary-differential-equations